# How to create a modular spring-boot application using module-info.java

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to create modular microservices running on `spring-boot RELEASE.2.0.3`

I recently discovered that my spring-boot applications did not start correctly, when upgrading my intellij IDEA.

I went back to my code published on GitHub ( https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-rises) only to discover that it did not run using `mvn spring-boot:run`either...

**Problem**:
Building the build published on GitHub with maven works fine. I was using wrong configuration for building and updated the maven pom in [jactor-persistence-orm](https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-rises/blob/master/jactor-applications/jactor-persistence-orm/pom.xml) with this code:

edit properties

```
<properties>
    ...
    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.8.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</maven-surefire-plugin.version>
</properties>
```

edit compiler plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-compiler-plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

edited surefire plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire-plugin.version}</version>
        </plugin>
```

I also edited my [module-info.java](https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-rises/blob/master/jactor-applications/jactor-persistence-orm/src/main/java/module-info.java) by adding the key-word `open`:

```
open module jactor.rises.persistence.orm {
    requires jactor.rises.commons;
    ...
```

Now the project compiles fine as a modular java 10 application, but my spring integration tests are failing due to invalid spring-context. All tests are running fine in my IntelliJIdea, but when executing maven on the command line, they fail...

I cannot grasp what is wrong and are hoping someone can spot it...

The simplest of tests (loading of the spring configuration): [JactorPersistenceTest.java](https://github.com/jactor-rises/jactor-rises/blob/master/jactor-applications/jactor-persistence-orm/src/test/java/com/github/jactor/rises/persistence/JactorPersistenceTest.java)

The surefire report:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Test set: com.github.jactor.rises.persistence.JactorPersistenceTest
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.015 s <<< FAILURE! - in com.github.jactor.rises.persistence.JactorPersistenceTest
com.github.jactor.rises.persistence.JactorPersistenceTest  Time elapsed: 0.015 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test
```

Comment: From my point of view it does not make sense to create a modular spring boot app cause all modules will be combined into a single jar file in the end ? Having clean interfaces etc. makes of course sense...

Comment: Some other hints about your project. If you use the most recent versions of maven-plugins like maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0 apart from that maven-surefire-plugin has already defined tests like `*Test.java` so there is no configuration needed as you did. If you use maven-surefire-plugin 2.22.0 you can make your configuration more simpler while using JUnit 5 as described here: https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html furthermore adding the plugins to plugins section is not necessary. Your web module is not part of the reactor which does not makes sense.

Comment: Also follow the suggestions Robert Scholte already made in your issue...

Comment: Nice example of how to use maven-surefire-plugin. I still gonna follow the starter from junit: https://github.com/junit-team/junit5-samples/blob/r5.2.0/junit5-jupiter-starter-maven/pom.xml

Comment: The example uses an old version of maven-surefire-plugin. See the link in my comment.....

Comment: Quote from junit 5 user guide, paragraph 4.2.2: Please use Maven Surefire 2.21.0 with the junit-platform-surefire-provider.

Comment: But unfortunately the use guide is not uptodate....the provider was needed with 2.21.0 and before but for 2.22.0 it is not needed anymore...

Comment: well... if I remove the provider... the build executes without errors, but no tests are run